# How to change background color of 'Strong Password' indicator in UITextField where textContentType = .newPassword

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

Title sums it up,

I have a `UITextField` with `textContentType` of `.newPassword` and on the black background it is making this:

[image]

How can I change this yellow color? (The app is always dark, so a dark/light agnostic solution would be ideal)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I shocked there appears to still be no way to style the password autofill stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard UI, so first I'd ask if you really want to mess with it. Users will already be familiar with this shade of yellow from Safari and trust it as being the same mechanism. But if you change the color, they'll think you're rolling your own and maybe won't trust it as much.

But if you do want to mess with it, the proper way would depend on how UIKit implements this feature. Is it a separate subview? Check in the view debugger. Do they adjust the displayed text's attributed string? Maybe subclass UITextField and override `textStyling(at:in:)`.

Comment: been there trying... all i found was that its a CALayer but i couldnt find the path to access it